# Python node with more than one publisher/subscriber

Tags: ros, python, node, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to make a ros python node that has more than one subscriber and more than one publisher? Are there examples of this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119746/python-node-with-more-than-one-publisher/subscriber/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.

I'm not aware of any good examples offhand, but the basic principle is that you simply instantiate multiple copies of the publisher and subscriber objects.

(I also believe that this question has been asked and answered before)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1